# Specification of Warsaw Color Theme

Tags: beamer, color

Does anyone know the specification (RGB) of the `Warsaw` blue color?  I want to make a custom block and want it to match the blue `Warsaw` color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need the RGB specification. The Warsaw theme uses several shades of blue, but all of them (for example, `structure.fg!75!black` and `structure.fg!50!black`) are variations of `structure.fg`, so you can say, for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamercolor{test}{bg=structure.fg,fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{test}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=1cm,dp=1cm,sep=1em]{test}
text
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's, however, the rgb specification of structure:

```
\definecolor{structure}{rgb}{0.2,0.2,0.7}
```